# Why is my action function being called on render?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to make a simple card view in material UI and when I implement adding and deleting items, the functions seem to be called several times on render.

I know usually the issue is having `action={myFunction}` but in this case I have definitely used `action={() => myFunction()}` so I'm not sure what's causing the function to be called on render.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

  function deleteItem(key: string) : void {
    console.log("deleting " + key);
    setGridItemMap(gridItemMap.filter( (value, i) => value.key !== key ));
  }

  function addItem() : void {
    setGridItemMap(gridItemMap.concat({key : "key1", props: props1}));
  }

  const props1 : GridItemProps = {title:"TitleProp1", body:"BodyProp1"};

  const [gridItemMap, setGridItemMap] = useState([
    {key: "key1", props: props1},
  ]);

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm">
      <Grid
        container
        direction="column"
        justify="space-evenly"
        alignItems="stretch"  
        spacing={1}
      >
        {gridItemMap.map( (entry) => (
          <Grid 
          container
          direction="row"
          spacing={1}
          >
            <GridItem key={entry.key} {...entry.props}></GridItem>
            <Fab action={() => deleteItem(entry.key)}>
              <DeleteIcon />
            </Fab>
          </Grid>
        ))}
        <Fab action = {() => addItem()}>
          <AddIcon />
        </Fab>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

When this is run I get the standard "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls `setState` inside `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops." error and the function is being called 100+ times suggesting I've managed to get an update loop somewhere but I can't find where

Comment: Where does Fab component come from?

Comment: Fab is a material-UI component but I can't find anyone else having this issue and I'm sure people are using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is tied to use use of the `action` prop. From the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/) on `ButtonBase` (which the `FAB` passes props to), the `action` prop is a "[c]allback fired when the component mounts". It seems you should pass the `addItem` function as the `onClick` prop rather than the `action` prop.

Also, as an aside, passing `() => addItem()` is equivalent to passing `addItem` as a callback on its own. The issue I believe you're referring to is when `onClick={ addItem() }` is used.

Comment: Yes you're right this was a silly error thanks for your help.

On the aside, I keep the anonymous function there for consistency and so I don't forget to add it in in the event that I later require arguments.